# Recalculating predicted values of neural network

Tags: r, neural-network

I have the following code in R using the nnet package to get the weights and predicted values:

```
test <- read.csv('ScaledData.csv',header=TRUE,sep = ",")

ANNtrain <- nnet(Price ~ Sqft + Bedrooms + Bathrooms,test[1:650,],size=2, maxit=5000, linout=TRUE)

ANNtrain$wts

ANNtrain$fitted.values
```

So I end up with these weights:

```
b->h1   2.3681687
i1->h1  -0.3898256
i2->h1  1.3565967
i3->h1  -1.8423163
b->h2   1.4826518
i1->h2  0.6584391
i2->h2  0.8964167
i3->h2  -1.3290192
b->o    1.0835755
h1->o   -4.977095
h2->o   4.2466241
```

I'm attempting to recalculate the fitted values, for example the fitted value of the first transaction is .025014924.

I'm using the sigmoid function on each hidden node which I understand to be 1/(1+exp(-a)) where a=the sum of the weighted values of each input variable.

I've been playing with this for a couple hours now and I'm stumped. I can't recalculate the fitted value no matter what I do. Any ideas? Does the linout parameter change the calculation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is not a specific function. It is a class of functions. Instances of this class are e. g. the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) `1/(1+exp(-a))` or [hyperbolic tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh).

When you set `linout=TRUE` you choose the identity function (`f(a) = a`) as activation function for the output layer, i. e. you actually don't have an activation function in the output layer.

Comment: Okay, I understand. And I've corrected my formula in my OP to reflect the logistic function, because I typed it wrong.

Comment: Btw. when you set linout=TRUE, the activation function of the output layer will be the identity, is that right?

Comment: that's what I'm wondering; I don't have a math background so I'm not sure what you mean by the identity, but it does seem like the calculation to get linear output would be different.

Comment: The identity function is f(a) = a, i. e. instead of a sigmoid activation function you have actually no activation function in the output layer.

Comment: funny enough I popped open my spreadsheet to check the solution after removing the activation function in the output layer, and I didn't even have to do anything; the answer was already there in a helper cell to calculate the sigmoid output. I'd like to give you answer credit--but since the final answer was only given in a comment, is it best to repost it as an 'answer'?

Comment: Sometimes the solution is easier than you think. :) I edited the answer.